# Conditions on rendering @users (exclude current_users and users with friend association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements, counter-cache

Currently, I'm doing the conditions in the view. I need to do it in **model or controller**, but haven't found a way to do it that works.

I have a view rendering 10 users via a partial that sorts them by their friends count (all examples simplified):

**Index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @users %>
```

**_partial.html.erb**

```
<% unless current_user == user or current_user.friending?(user) %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

**models/user.rb**

```
scope :top, :order => "friends_count DESC"
```

**users_controller.rb/index**

```
@users = User.top.limit(10)
```

But in my case, it checks the validations in the partial for each user. How can I do it more effectively in the scope or controller and check for all?

Thanks greatly for all answers. Hugely appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it helps under your conditions, but why not use the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
  scope :top, order("friends_count DESC")
  scope :skip_user, lambda{|user| where("id != ?", user.id) }
  scope :skip_user_friends, lambda{|user| where("friend_id != ?", user.id }
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
@users = User.top.skip_user(current_user).skip_user_friends(current_user).limit(10)
```

Comment: Good work! This also has one more plus. Since the overall queries is scoped in chain, it will only do a single optimized SQL query over the table while retrieving `@users`.

Comment: Yes, that was the objective.  I like breaking the scopes down into smaller focused bits because they are easier to reuse in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting your `@users` in the controller, you can use `#select`.

```
@users = User.top.reject { |user| current_user == user or current_user.friending?(user) }.limit(10)
```

Comment: He is using `unless` in his view; thus, rejecting those `users` which match the given condition(s). I think, you should be using `reject` instead of `select` here, for that.

Comment: or just negate the conditionals:

User.top.select { |user| current_user != user || !current_user.friendling?(user) }.limit(10)

Comment: @bjhaid technically, yes. But that will only make the overall statement a bit unclear for third person => !ruby_convention. :)

Comment: Updated to be reject.